# Pyserial won't readline data from arduino

Tags: arduino, pyserial, serial-communication

I have problem with reading data from my Arduino.
Here is what I send from my arduino to Pycharm:

```
Serial.println("ArduinoMega");
```

and here is my code with Pycharm which reads and compares to b'ArduinoMega':

```
ser = serial.Serial(port,baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
            ser.write(b'\x00')
            print(port)
            serial.time.sleep(2)
            rec = (ser.readline(len(b'ArduinoMega')))
            print(rec)
            if rec == b'ArduinoMega':
                ser.close()
                return port
            ser.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, pyserial sets dtr pin high when opening new connection. Arduino boards are made to reset themselves when connected to with high dtr, so your Arduino resets when you open connection with your computer and does not initialize its serial port in time when you send your package and expect reply.

To solve this programmatically, you can change your code to:

```
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = port
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.timeout = 1
ser.dtr = False
ser.open()
ser.write(b'\x00')
rec = ser.read(len(b'ArduinoMega')
if rec == b'ArduinoMega':
    ser.close()
    return port
ser.close()
```

Also, note change in ser.read... line.